# SDL2 Alpha Not Showing Up

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2, alpha

In a game loop that I have, part of the drawing section is:

```c
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 100);
SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &blur);
```

`renderer` is my renderer and `blur` is my rect that takes up the whole screen:

```c
SDL_Rect blur;
blur.x = 0;
blur.y = 0;
blur.w = 640;
blur.h = 480;
```

My problem is that the rect isn't semi transparent. Whenever it draws it, all there is is black.
You cant even see the text that I have underneath. How do I fix this? Does my renderer not support
alpha?

Comment: Have you called `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode()` beforehand?

Comment: What @FrédéricHamidi said is most likely, but it's also worth asking - Could you provide more context to the current SDL renderer/window set up?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the alpha value isn't affecting anything is because you need to specify which colour blending method you want to use beforehand with this [function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode):

```c
int SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_BlendMode blendMode)
```

The [`blendMode`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlendMode) parameter controls how colour blending works. For alpha color blending, use `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND`:

```c
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 100);
SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &blur);
```